# How to margin text based on clip path edge?

Tags: html, css

---

I'm trying to `margin-left` text based on a clipped path div to create a staggered look. Currently, I have something like this:

```css
#parent {
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

#text1 {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#text2 {
  margin-left: 7.5%;
}

#text3 {
  margin-left: 5%;
}

#text4 {
  margin-left: 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <p id='text1'>Text 1</p>
  <p id='text2'>Text 2</p>
  <p id='text3'>Text 3</p>
  <p id='text4'>Text 4</p>
</div>
```

However, I want to try to do this more efficiently. I want it so each text doesn't need a separate `margin-left`. I'm picturing something where each text is margin-lefting based on the new clipped path edge rather than the original edge of the rectangle:
[image]

Then the code could look something like this:

```
<div id='parent'>
  <p class='text'>Text 1</p>
  <p class='text'>Text 2</p>
  <p class='text'>Text 3</p>
  <p class='text'>Text 4</p>
</div>

#parent {
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.text {
  margin-left: 2%; // Not using exact numbers, but something like this
}
```

Unsure if there's something out there, assuming CSS related, that will let me achieve this.

Comment: Have you looked into CSS shapes? ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_shapes)) They might let you offload all the complexity of text alignment to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the job of `shape-outside`

```css
#parent {
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

#parent:before {
  content: "";
  float: left; /* we need float with shape-outside */
  width: 10%; /* same value as the first value on the polygon of the parent */
  height: 100%;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0% 100%); /* triangle shape */
  shape-margin: 10px; /* this will control the gap */
}

/* an extra wrapper with grid or flex is needed to use height: 100% */
.box {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id='parent'>
    <p id='text1'>Text 1</p>
    <p id='text2'>Text 2</p>
    <p id='text3'>Text 3</p>
    <p id='text4'>Text 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```